# Crashing when reading in strings

Tags: c++, string, crash

The program compiles and runs, however when I enter 2 or more entries, it crashes right at the moment I enter the second call number.  Here is what I enter and the call stack:

[image: crash]

"Unhandled exception at 0x013A6EC6 in Library Holdings.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

This time it crashed before I got to enter the second call #.

Here is another crash that happened, crashes at different points for some reason, but this was the most common crash I was getting
[image: crash]

Unhandled exception at 0x779B016E (ntdll.dll) in Library Holdings.exe: 0x00000000: The operation completed successfully.

I was wondering how do I get it to stop crashing?

LibraryDrv.h:

```
#ifndef _LIBRARYDRV_H
#define _LIBRARYDRV_H

#include "Holding.h"
#include "Recording.h"
#include "Book.h"

Holding* inputHolding();

#endif
```

LibraryDr.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LibraryDrv.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
Holding *hptr[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hptr[i] = inputHolding();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hptr[i]->print();
}

return 0;
}

Holding* inputHolding() {
char selection;
char title[50];
int callNumber = 0;
char author[50];
char performer[50];
char format;

cout << "Enter B for book, R for recording: ";
cin >> selection;

if (selection == 'B') {
    cout << "Enter book title: ";
    cin >> title;

    cout << "Enter book author: ";
    cin >> author;

    cout << "Enter call number: ";
    cin >> callNumber;

    Book* aBook = new Book(title, callNumber, author);
    return aBook;
}
else  if (selection == 'R') {
    cout << "Enter recording title: ";
    cin >> title;

    cout << "Enter performer: ";
    cin >> performer;

    cout << "Enter format: (M)P3, (W)AV, (A)IFF: ";
    cin >> format;

    cout << "Enter call number: ";
    cin >> callNumber;

    Recording* aRecording = new Recording(title, callNumber, performer,     format);
    return aRecording;
}
else {
    cout << "Incorrect selection" << endl;
    return nullptr;
}
```

}

Holding.h

```
#ifndef _HOLDING_H
#define _HOLDING_H

class Holding {
protected:
int callNumber;
char* title;

public:
Holding();
Holding(const Holding&);
Holding(char*, int);
virtual void print() = 0;
virtual ~Holding();
};

#endif
```

Holding.cpp

```
#include "Holding.h"
#include "String.h"

Holding::Holding() {

}

Holding::Holding(const Holding& copy) {
title = new char[strlen(copy.title) + 1];

strcpy_s(title,sizeof(title), copy.title);
callNumber = copy.callNumber;
}

Holding::Holding(char* copy, int inputCall) {
int len = strlen(copy) + 1;
title = new char[len];

strcpy_s(title, sizeof(char) * len, copy); 
callNumber = inputCall;
}

Holding::~Holding() {
delete [] title;
}
```

Book.h:

```
#ifndef _BOOK_H
#define _BOOK_H

#include "Holding.h"

class Book : public Holding {
private:
char* author;

public:
Book();
Book(const Book&);
Book(char*, int, char*);
virtual void print();
virtual ~Book();
};

#endif
```

Book.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Holding.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include "String.h"

using namespace std;

Book::Book() {
author = nullptr;
}

Book::Book(const Book& copy) : Holding(copy) {
author = new char[strlen(copy.author) + 1];

strcpy_s(author, sizeof(author), copy.author);
}

Book::Book(char* inputTitle, int inputCallNum, char* inputAuthor) : Holding(inputTitle,    inputCallNum) {
int len = strlen(inputAuthor) + 1;
author = new char[len];

strcpy_s(author, sizeof(author)*len, inputAuthor);
}

Book::~Book() {
delete [] author;
}

void Book::print() {
cout << "BOOK: " << author << " " << title << " " << callNumber << endl;
}
```

Recording.h:

```
#ifndef _RECORDING_H
#define _RECORDING_H

#include "Holding.h"

class Recording : public Holding {
private:
char* performer;
char format;

public:
Recording();
Recording(const Recording&);
Recording(char*, int, char*, char);
virtual void print();
virtual ~Recording();

};

#endif
```

Recording.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "String.h"
#include "Holding.h"
#include "Recording.h"

using namespace std;

Recording::Recording() {

}

Recording::Recording(const Recording& copy) : Holding(copy) {
int len = strlen(copy.performer) + 1;
performer = new char[len];

strcat_s(performer, sizeof(performer)*len, copy.performer);
format = copy.format;
}

Recording::Recording(char* inputTitle, int inputCallNum, char* inputPerformer, char     inputFormat)
: Holding(inputTitle, inputCallNum) {
int len = strlen(inputPerformer) + 1;
performer = new char[len];

strcpy_s(performer, sizeof(performer)*len, inputPerformer);
format = inputFormat;
}

Recording::~Recording() {
delete [] performer;
}

void Recording::print() {
cout << "RECORDING: " << title << " " << performer << " (" << format << ") " <<     callNumber << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is this?  Debugging for ants?  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: You also pasted `Book.h` twice (no `Book.cpp`)

Comment: My ant friends are telling me there's something wrong in line 12/11.  Not sure which file though.  Ants haven't figured that out yet.  What do the two lines (the ones that reference these line numbers) say?  Can you figure out what lines those are and point those out?

Comment: I'm not surprised what with all the pointers and manual memory management.

Comment: Okay, I guess the ant references are cutting it.  The screenshots are completely indecipherable.  You need to copy and paste the error message in as plaintext if you want any help at all.  The error messages are crucially important to finding the source of your problem, and here, they only exist in your screenshots...which can only be read by ants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cin can only take in one word when using '>>'. So when you entered "good bye" cin assign "good" to author and since "bye" was still in the buffer, it automatically tried to assign it to callNumber, but since callNumber is an int var, it threw a bad bit exception. So either enter only one word inputs, or change input methods to the following:

```
///cout statement here
getline(cin, title);
cin.ignore();

///cout statement here
getline(cin, author);
cin.ignore()
```

the cin.ignore is to simply ignore '\n' which is what the enter key appends to an inputted string. If cin.ignore is left out, you'll run into the same issue because '\n' is still in the buffer.